# Pagina web forms con master page publicada en IIS no carga por ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: c#, webforms, iis

Cree una pagina con Web Forms y Master Page en VS2022 c#, cuando la ejecuto en mi equipo con IISExpress, funciona todo bien, pero al publicarla en el IIS Server de la dmz, al intentar acceder a la pagina no se conecta y de este error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
No se si estare publicando mal mi pagina en IIS o es un problema de configuracion del IIS. Pero he publicado otras paginas sin problemas. Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Verifica que la versión de .net del proyecto esté instalada en el servidor

Comment: Instale la ultima version y aun asi sigue igual. No se realmente que me falta hacer para que funcione la pagina.